# How to get data placed after question mark in URL adress?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This is part of my web api Controller:

```
public IQueryable<Word> GetPeople()
{
    return db.People;
}
```

This function returns list of people. It works, but sometimes I don't want to get everything and from the client side I want to specify what I want.

Using ajax I can send some data to server (and it appears in URL after question mark):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/People",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {giveme: "peopleaddedtoday"}
})
```

How can I receive that data on server side?

Comment: did you map that in your routing? btw its called the query string.

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks, I didn't know how to ask google for that ^^ Answer to question: I don't know. I'm new in asp.net

Comment: Why are you returning People while specifying Word in return type

Comment: Agree with @husnain_sys .In any case, you might want to modify the webapi to accept the filter parameter like 'public IQueryable<People> GetPeople(string giveme){ db.People.Where(p=> p.AddedToday == true)}'

Comment: Url of your ajax request will be ControllerName/GetPeople, your cotroller will expect parameter "giveme". Make the return type correct as identified by @Nilesh. It should work

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like this:

```
    public IQueryable<Word> GetPeople([FromUri] string giveme)
    {
       var people = db.People;

       if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(giveme))
       {
          if(giveme == "peopleaddedtoday")
          {
             people = db.People.Where(p => p.DateAdded == DateTime.Now.Date);
          }
       }

        return people;
    }
```